# My audio time progress bar is not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

So i'm want to creat a function that when i click on the progress bar the current time of the audio wil change, i'm using input range to make a progess bar

```
 <div class="player__duration">
                <div class="player__duration--start"><p></p></div>
                <input class="player__duration--bar" type="range" name="" id="" step="1"  value="0" >
                <div class="player__duration--end"><p></p></div>
            </div>
```

this is my javascript

```
let counter = 0
let song = new Audio()
song.src = songs[counter].src

let changeTime = () =>{
    let input = document.querySelector("input")
    input.addEventListener("change",()=>{
        song.currentTime = input.value
    })
}
let play = () =>{
    let playBtn = document.querySelector(".player__btn--play")
    let pauseBtn = document.querySelector(".player__btn--pause")
    playBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        pauseBtn.style.display="block"
        playBtn.style.display="none"
        song.play()
        updateProgressBar()
        totalTime()
    })
}

let pause = () =>{
    let playBtn = document.querySelector(".player__btn--play")
    let pauseBtn = document.querySelector(".player__btn--pause")
    pauseBtn.addEventListener( "click", ()=>{
        playBtn.style.display = "block"
        pauseBtn.style.display = "none"
        song.pause()
    })
}
let checkTime = (i) =>{
    if(i<10){
        i = "0"+ i
    }
    return i
}

let updateProgressBar =()=>{
    let input = document.querySelector("input")
    let currentT = document.querySelector(".player__duration--start")
    let range = input.value
    input.max = song.duration
    song.addEventListener("timeupdate",()=>{
        range = Math.floor(song.currentTime)
        input.value = range
        let minute = Math.floor(range / 60)
        let second = Math.floor(range % 60)
        minute = checkTime(minute)
        second = checkTime(second)
        currentT.innerText=minute + ":" +second
    })
}

let totalTime = () =>{
    let totalTime = document.querySelector(".player__duration--end")
    let minute = Math.floor(song.duration / 60)
    let second = Math.floor(song.duration % 60)
    minute = checkTime(minute)
    second = checkTime(second)
    totalTime.innerText = minute + ":" +second
}
play()
changeTime()
pause()
```

So i use the change event for input range to update the current time of the audio whenever i click on the progress bar, it work fine, but sometime i have to double click, or triple click to make it work and i dont know why, how can i change the current time with only single click. Thank you !

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverlow! I know this is your first question and I'm here to help. For someone to help you there is a few things you can do to help them out:
- Remove any redundant code leaving only the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the issue.
- Provide a working example, use https://stackblitz.com/ or something similar to provide a running example of the issue.

This will make it a lot easier for the community to help you out with your issue and it will provide more help for future users! Welcome to the community :)

Comment: tkank you, yes i'm new to StackOverflow, i''ll be more becareful next time